# tomcat can't load my webapp in ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, ubuntu

I start javaEE with tomcat and linux ubuntu.

i installed tomcat on linux successfully and see its first page in `127.0.0.1:8080`

that was : "it works..."

By the first example in my book, i create a directory called `jspbook` in `webapps` and a sub directory `WEB-INF`in `jspbook` that contains this `web.xml`:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" version="2.4">
```

And another xml file called `jspbook.xml` in webapps directory:

```
<Context path="/jspbook" docBase="jspbook" debug="0"/>
```

Now after restarting tomcat, it doesn't display a blank directory in browser by `127.0.0.1:8080/jspbook/` in linux

But i try it in windows and it displayed a blank directory correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must tell you, 1st create a simple html file and check your browser can acces that directory or not
In jspbook create a html file called `test.html`

```
<html>
<head><title> Its Test<title></head>
<body> Its Working Fine</body>
</html>
```

Now open: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/jspbook/test.html` 
If that works then there is some problem in your java code, if it dosen't work check you have given read permission for groups and other or not

Comment: the same problem, Error 404

Answer (score 0):

Which browser, what exactly did you really try? The URL `127.0.0.1:8080:jspbook/` is invalid, it should be `127.0.0.1:8080/jspbook/` instead. And, of course, if the Windows machine is not the same as the Linux machine, then `127.0.0.1` (aka. `localhost`) will not take you from your Windows to your Linux.